# XCode 4.2 w/ Three20: Undefined symbols for architecture i386: TTIsInDebugger

Tags: objective-c, three20, xcode4.2

I upgraded to XCode 4.2 and my project is failing to link with Three20. I get this error. Any ideas?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
```

"TTIsInDebugger()", referenced from:
   ...my code stack here...
   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this, see https://github.com/facebook/three20/issues/779 for resolution.